# Ubuntu: Passenger cannot find SSL for curl

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, passenger, ruby-on-rails-3

I am installing passenger as an nginx module on ubuntu, and while installing i get the error that Curl development headers with SSL support are not available. It suggests to "run apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev or libcurl4-gnutls-dev, whichever you prefer"

i ran apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev but it still gives the same error... Googling does not give a usefull result.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this?

Comment: yes and no... i reinstalled ubuntu, and things worked...

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat the same problem. Installing openssl libraries it didn't seem solve anything, but after I removed and reinstalled rails it worked.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart